# zsh vs bash on query string object

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, zsh, node-modules

I'm running a very basic NodeJS application just to mess around with and learn ZSH but the queryStringObject I've defined from my parsedUrl in bash returns {fizz:'buzz'} and zsh returns [Object: null prototype] {}. What can I do in ZSH or in my app to make this console.log the JSON formatting instead of what ZSH is currently giving me?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true); //true indicates to include query object
  var queryStringObject = parsedUrl.query;
  res.end('Hello World\n'); //curls to dom

  console.log('Request received with query string:',queryStringObject);
}
```

I'll happily go back to using Bash to get what I'm used to seeing or simply use postman for this kind of testing, but I'm trying to learn little bits and pieces of ZSH as I go along and this behavior is likely to hit me often so I'd like to know how to best handle it.

Comment: What does this have to do with bash or zsh?

Comment: @Herohtar *somehow* this node applications does something with them but I agree, it's not clear what nor how. We need to know what is this doing precisely - so far, it reseives some request and...gets a queryStringObject which is incorrect at one point. No idea how bash or zsh produce queryStringObject nor how they are used nor what is really happening.

Comment: @cardmstr can you please give some clear code to understand your question?

Comment: The code is clear; it's a node program that creates a HTTP server that gets the query string from the request URL and logs it to the console. But I would expect a question that says there is a problem related to `bash` and `zsh` to actually contain some `bash` and/or `zsh` commands that demonstrate how they are being used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It *sounds* like you are using curl or something on the command line to make an HTTP request, and the problem is with the command line you are using (which, as Herohtar pointers out, you failed to include in the question).

Answer (score -3):

It isn't a `bash`, `zsh` or any specific shell problem. Try `JSON.parse()` to print  your object in `JSON` format.

```js
console.log('Request received with query string:',JSON.parse(queryStringObject));
```

Comment: Neither example of the value given in the question is JSON, so that will throw an error.